# Screen briefly turns black when I move on the chair in a specific way

Tags: ubuntu, display, hdmi, ghost

Sorry if I am writing this in a wrong Stack Exchange site, I looked at all of them and this seemed like the most proper one for this weird stuff.

Based on a complete truth.

Straight to the point. Environment:
I have a laptop (ThinkPad E570) with Ubuntu 20.04.5 on it connected to IIYAMA X4071UHSU via the 30HZ HDMI port. I have tried replacing with many cables, including an expensive one with gold plated endings and a thick shielded wire. Both a built-in screen and the IIYAMA are on and work in extended desktop mode (FULL HD on built-in and 4k without scaling on IIYAMA).
There are a few power cords behind the 4K screen. In front of the screen I have MX Keys and MX Anywhere 3 running on unified receiver + solaar software (so it's basically a bluetooth wrapper).
Also between the screens I have a digital clock - some periodical chinesium hit. A little bit further is a router HUAWEI B535-232 (LTE + WIFI 5 dual band on) and finally HP DESKJET Ink Advantage 4535 with it's HP polling via WIFI I think.
Plus a 4G phone and whatever the neighbours have (single family houses, 30-50m apart).

The reason why I described all the possible EM signal sources nearby is that it relates heavily to one of the last remaining theories of mine as to what is going on - a strong interference happening in reaction to my movement.

Steps to reproduce:
Considering that you have a chair that can rotate and lean back - lean back, rotate a little to the left and put your legs on your desk. Relax deeply. Watching a movie or having a beer is optional. Wait until you need to go to bathroom. Now take your legs down as in you were to go somewhere, away from your workbench. Blink, blink. The screen turns black (as if image over HDMI cable got distorted of turned off for a second, the screen itself is still on) and then back to normal picture.

**Literally, my screen turns black when I take my feet off the workbench.**

This has been occurring for about 1.5 year now and I managed to observe, that this happens randomly and that it does not matter if I take my legs off slowly or fast or whether my feet were touching any cables. I also tried wiggling the connected cables a little and nothing, solid connection.

Now I am an atheist and do not believe in fairy tales, but going with the Arthur Conan Doyle'

```
When you have eliminated all which is impossible, then whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.
```

there is this tingling option at the back of my mind that someone... something... from other planes of existence is displeased with the inglorious way that I sit when I work and is giving me a nudge.

Anyone has any sane (and insane alike) ideas what the heck is going on? Perhaps there is some weird behavior reported with the devices I listed above...

Oh I almost forgot - the same thing was happening in another room in another house. I moved recently and the only thing that is the same is the wooden desk that my set-up stands on. So I guess a very devoted evil ghost or demon is after me and it is not just about kicking me out of the property.

Comment: "the only thing that is the same is the wooden desk" – And you. "Whatever remains" includes your eyes and brain. Has anyone else witnessed such blink caused by your movement?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski until now it has been a secret ;) Maybe I will set up a camera.